# How can I get RTPBin to not attempt to synchronize multiple streams?

Tags: gstreamer

I've noticed that single stream latency is increased when another stream is added and is connected to the same RTPBin element.

I suspect that RTPBin is attempting to synchronize both based on each stream's SR reports. Is there a way to force RTPBin to not synchronize multiple streams and instead allow packets through as they leave (or arrive)?

The latency can be quite significant, where a single stream is 150ms which increases to 550ms the moment another stream is added. The two streams are from WebRTC in the Chrome browser.

```
stream_1 ----> rtpbin_1
                        \
                         [ audio/video mixed/composited ] --> rtpbin_1 and rtpbin_2
                        /
stream_2 ----> rtpbin_2
```